# is there any way to check which commits were merged to a branch on a specific day?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a master branch and another named release/system2. I had several commits pushed to the master branch, and two days ago, I made a merge to release/system2. After that, system2 broke the system due to some issues in the latest code in the master branch.
Is there any way I could check which commits were merged into the release/system2 branch two days ago, ignoring the commits merged before that specific day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note I don't think you're asking exactly the correct question:

> Is there any way I could check which commits were merged into the release/system2 branch two days ago

Based on your description, since you already know which merge caused the problem, I don't think you care about other merges that may have happened that day as well (either before or after that merge). I suspect what you really want is to isolate the commits that were merged in during that specific merge. Therefore, let's call the merge commit ID created by the merge of `master` into `release/system2` commit `M`.

All of the commits brought into `release/system2` by that merge can be identified with:

```
git log M^1..M
```

Perhaps equally helpful in identifying the problem file(s) would be a diff of those same two commits (parent 1 of the merge commit with the merge commit).

**Note:** this assume the first-parent is in fact the previous version of `release/system2` before the merge. This would normally be the case, but it's possible it could be backwards, for example if that merge had conflicts that you had to resolve, and if your temporary branch used to resolve them started from `master` and merged in `release/system2` instead of the other way around, and then if you merged that temporary branch into `release/system2` using a fast-forward merge. If you're in this scenario then use `M^2` instead of `M^1`.

**Side Note:** if you actually did care to know about every commit brought into the branch in a 24 hour period, you could change the log command to be `git log X..Y` where `X` is the last commit on the branch that you know was good, and `Y` is the first commit where you know for sure you had the problem. My understanding is that you already know this and X = M^1 and Y = M.

Comment: this helped me getting the commits'

Answer (score 0):

**Check all git log by date range:**

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad - %an: %s" --after="2016-01-31" --until="2023-03-10"
```

**result:**

```
Mon Jul 25 22:38:56 2022 +0500 - zakk: implemented mongo altas
Sun Jul 24 23:53:57 2022 +0500 - zakk: implemented mongodb
Sat Jul 23 18:30:32 2022 +0500 - zakk: applied css
Thu Jul 21 21:29:22 2022 +0500 - zakk: fisrt commit
```

**check git log by formating the date:**

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h - %an, %ar : %s"
```

**result:**

```
86d00ca - zakk, 3 days ago : implemented mongo altas
987cdb5 - zakk, 4 days ago : implemented mongodb
8f9240b - zakk, 5 days ago : applied css
10f1e4e - zakk, 7 days ago : fisrt commit
```

**Note:** this will print all log including `commits` and `merges`

Comment: Note this will show you commits that were created on specific dates, but not the dates they were merged.

Comment: The `merge` is considered a `single commit` , when two branchs are merged the git inserts a `commit` in repo.

Comment: `cf2c7beb - zakk, 4 weeks ago : Merge branch 'main' into ayoub`

Comment: The question is asking which commits were merged in. So the merge commit date is relevant, but the dates of the commits getting merged is not. For example, suppose you know about your merge commit from your comment, `cf2c7beb`. This question is asking: "Which commits did that merge commit bring into branch `ayoub`?